# Charting components in Flex 4 opensource SDK

Tags: flex4, flexbuilder

Charting components in Flex 4 opensource SDK are free or not.

Is there any difference between **Opensource Flex SDK 4** and **Free Adobe Flex SDK** interms of charting components.

will we need to get license if we use it for commercial purpose...?

Any help please..?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Flex 4, they are free. You no longer need to buy Flash Builder Professional license to use those components.

Comment: Is there any difference between Opensource Flex SDK 4 and Free Adobe Flex SDK interms of components.?

Comment: I don't think there are 2 differents distributions of Flex 4 SDK. Where did you see this?